# Do something only if date created greater than

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-server-2008

I've got this piece of batch code:

```
for /D %%f in (E:\images\*) do E:\jpegoptim.exe -v --strip-all "%%f\*.jpg"
```

I need to add a condition inside the 'do' statement, to run the executable only on the files whose creation date is greater than '2014-01-01'.

I know `DIR /T` lists files with creation dates, but how can I integrate it in my code? Is there a way to simply get the date of %%f ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the modifier `%%~tx` in the `FOR` loop. You can do like this :

```
@echo off

set $Lim=20140101

setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b/a-d "E:\images\*.txt"') do (
 set $FileDate=%%~ta
 set $FileDate=!$FileDate:~6,4!!$FileDate:~3,2!!$FileDate:~0,2!
 if !$FileDate! Gtr %$Lim% echo E:\jpegoptim.exe -v --strip-all "%%~fa"
)
```

Test it and remove the `echo` if the output is correct for you

Comment: The format of the `%%~ta` changes by locale.  Fabio will have to verify it is the same in his region.